# i want to make cron job for the url of nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, url, cron

Inside postman my URL "http://localhost:1000/api/coupon/coupondeactivate" working fine. I want to make this URL in cron job. So I used it in below form.

```
wget http://localhost:1000/api/coupon/coupondeactivate --header "Referer: localhost:1000"
```

But when I try to paste above URL in CMD then I found below bug so please kindly help me to solve this issue.

> ```
> Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
> Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:1000... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
> 2016-12-27 12:27:19 ERROR 404: Not Found.
> ```

Comment: Have you tried using the `cURL` command generated by Postman instead? (It's not `wget`... but maybe it'll help you get an answer faster?) https://www.getpostman.com/docs/creating_curl Otherwise, I would recommend inspecting the Postman vs `wget` requests from the server's perspective to see what's different about them.

Comment: hello therobinkim, i also tried curl command in the cmd and write  curl -s http://localhost:1000/api/coupon/coupondeactivate

Comment: at that time Cannot GET /api/coupon/coupondeactivate
error comes

Comment: How is your server behaving at that point? Did it acknowledge receipt of the request?

Comment: website on this port  working fine

Comment: but above api url not working

Comment: Please remove the here irrelevant tag `cmd` See the tag description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello please try the following curl request for your url.

```
watch -n 5 curl --request POST  urlname
```

run above in cmd it working fine for me

Comment: it runs the url every 5 second you can increase your time by removing 5 second and put your own time